# How to verify if the web services are called from an android mobile application

Tags: android, api, rest, web-services

We have two subdomains, `api.example.com` written in Laravel, and `logs.example.com` written in FastAPI. Our web services used to be a monolithic system and the logs micro-service was integrated, however, we need to separate the services of the log.

When a user (authenticated or anonymous) see some of the pages of our mobile application, some APIs from the logs micro-service are called to store some data to Elasticsearch for data analysis.

We need to verify that the request is sent from our android application to prevent people from calling the API through postman or even from other android applications.

I would like to know how this verficiation can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you set some header from the app? Generate data using some algo on the app side and set it header. Second option: you may check the user-agent in request it will be different for ios and android apps even you can customize it app side.

Comment: @Muneesh Unfortunately people can decode the mobile applications and I can't generate some data. Our application has about 1M users and it is very critical. I need a stable and verified solution.

Comment: A JWT based solution perhaps - https://proandroiddev.com/jwt-authentication-and-refresh-token-in-android-with-retrofit-interceptor-authenticator-da021f7f7534?gi=990362f8f268

Comment: You can use HMAC based solution to verify App<-->API communication. https://medium.com/@jarredmartin/secure-app-api-communication-using-an-hmac-316314b63445